# Java Credit Card Interest calculator keeps thinking data invalid

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class CreditCardInterest {

public static void main(String[] args) {
// Variable Declarations
Scanner k = new Scanner(System.in); // create a keyboard object
System.out.println("Credit Card Interestn" + "---------------------------    \n");

System.out.println("This program calculates how much interest you need to pay on your credit card \n" + "balance.");



String answer;
double balance;
int fixedcycle = 31;
int cycle;
double payment;
double interest;
double result;

System.out.println("Did you pay your balance in full and on time?");
System.out.print("(Please Answer Yes or No): ");
answer = k.nextLine();

if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("Yes")) {
  System.out.println("\nCongratulations on paying the full amount!\n" + "No interest will be charged on your card.\n" + "Thank you for using the Credit Card Interest Calculator!\n" +
    "Your system will now exit");
  System.exit(0);
}

if (answer.equalsIgnoreCase("No")) {
  System.out.print("Please enter the previous balance on your credit card: ");
  balance = k.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("How many days before the end of the cycle did you pay?: ");
  cycle = k.nextInt();
  System.out.print("How much was paid then?: ");
  payment = k.nextDouble();
  System.out.print("What is the interest rate of your credit card?: ");
  interest = k.nextDouble();
  System.out.println("");

  if (balance > 0 && cycle > 1 && cycle < 31 && payment <= balance && payment > 0 && interest == 17 && interest == 18.5) {
    result = ((payment * fixedcycle) - (balance * cycle)) / fixedcycle;
    System.out.println("The interest charge on your credit card is $" + result);

  } else {

    System.out.println("You entered some Invalid Data!!!\n" + "No Interest calculation will be provided\n\n");
    System.out.println("Balance: " + balance);
    System.out.println("This value should be positive and cannot be zero.\n");
    System.out.println("Day of the billing cycle:" + cycle);
    System.out.println("This value should be between 1 and 31.\n");
    System.out.println("Payment amount: " + payment);
    System.out.println("This value should be positive and less than or equal to the balance.\n");
    System.out.println("Annual interest rate: " + interest);
    System.out.println("This value should be either 17.0 or 18.5.\n\n");
  }

}

}
}
```

It keeps going right to the else, at first I had all the boolean operators switched and had the interest calculation as the else but it always thought the users Data was wrong then too. (interest has to be 17.5 or 18 btw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (balance > 0 && cycle > 1 && cycle < 31 && payment <= balance && payment > 0 && interest == 17 && interest == 18.5) {
```

Check this condition better because is always false:

**if interest is 17:**

interest == 17 //true

interest == 18.5 //false

interest == 17 && interest == 18.5 //false

anything && false //**false**

**if interest is 18.5:**

interest == 17 //false

interest == 18.5 //true

interest == 17 && interest == 18.5 //false

anything && false //**false**

**if interest is 200:**

interest == 17 //false

interest == 18.5 //false

interest == 17 && interest == 18.5 //false

anything && false //**false**

What you are looking for is probably

```
        if (balance > 0 && cycle > 1 && cycle < 31 && payment <= balance && payment > 0 && (interest == 17 || interest == 18.5)) {
```